# Understanding the unit of area for standard deviational ellipse

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I am using the `aspace` package to calculate the standard deviational ellipse of a set of points. Test shapefile with 5 points zipped [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zx2nzf4jvxus7s/testSHP.zip?dl=0).

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(aspace)
library(rgdal)
shpfile <- readShapePoints("testSHP.shp")
coords <- shpfile@coords
calc_sde(points=coords)
plot_sde(plotnew = TRUE)
r.SDE$Area.sde
```

The area is 2824712729.

I think I am getting tripped up by the coordinate system:

```
coords
#  coords.x1 coords.x2
#0   3667152   8861968
#1   3713150   8878606
#2   3714374   8843128
#3   3683545   8834809
#4   3690396   8854383
```

The shapefile is set to `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`.

1. What are the units for this area?
2. How can I project the coordinates in decimal degrees?

[image]

Comment: Those coordinates are not lat/long decimal degrees. You need to find out the actual coordinate system. I would imagine that the projection units are in meters.

Comment: In your picture your units are meters, so your units for area would be square meters.  `2824712729m^2` or `2824.7km^2`.  Looking at your grid that area looks about right.

Comment: Your title has "SDE" ((which hasn't existed in a long time) and your question body references "SHP" (which is a suffix, not a format) -- these are not the same thing.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I think it's WGS84. Is there a way to confirm?

Comment: @Midavalo it might be meters, but I believe that `plot_sde()` uses the "m" label by default.

Comment: Don't use `readShapePoints` - it ignores the `testSHP.prj` coordinate system specification file. In this case, the .prj is lat-long coordinates, which is clearly wrong for these numbers. I suspect you lost the coordinate system at some other point in your workflow because you used `readShapePoints` instead of `readOGR` or `raster::shapefile`, both of which do the right thing with .prj files.

Comment: Thanks, @Spacedman. I did not know that about `readShapePoints`.

Comment: @Kazuhito, I think you are right. My best guess at the moment is `+proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

Comment: We created the points from raster layer with utm projection (36S), datum WGS84. Do I delete the current prj file and define the CRS?

Comment: Because it's mathematically impossible for a (correct) SD ellipse to strictly include all the points in its dataset, the ellipse shown is obviously too big.  You might want to look into that before you go much further.

Comment: @Kazuhito this is what I needed for Question 2. As JeffreyEvans and Midavalo noted, the units are meters. Still looking into whuber's note about the incorrect ellipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(maptools); library(sp); library(aspace); library(rgdal)
shpfile <- readShapePoints("testSHP.shp")
proj4string(shpfile) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32736")  # UTM36S
coords <- shpfile@coords
calc_sde(points=coords)
plot_sde(plotnew = TRUE)
r.SDE$Area.sde
# [1] 2824692311 (m2)

shpfile_lonlat <- spTransform(shpfile, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
LonLat <- shpfile_lonlat@coords
calc_sde(points=LonLat)

# export SDE as shapefile
shp <- shapefiles::convert.to.shapefile(sdeloc,sdeatt,"id",5)
write.shapefile(shp, "./SDE_shape", arcgis=T)

# read SDE shapefile
Ellips <- readShapeSpatial("./SDE_shape.shp", 
                            proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
plot(Ellips, border= "blue", axes= TRUE)
points(shpfile_lonlat)

# calculate area on WGS84 ellipsoid
library(geosphere)
areaPolygon(Ellips, a=6378137, f=1/298.257223563) # WGS84
# [1] 2216829475 (m2)
```

As `r.SDE$Area.sde` seems to calculate planimetric area, I tried ellipsoidal area on WGS84 using {geosphere} package.

Comment: this is great, @Kazuhito

Comment: Hi @EricGreen Correction to the code with apologies. In `write.shapefile()` function `"SDE_shape.shp"` should have been `"SDE_shape"` without .shp (edited the answer). Apparently you have fixed the code yourself :)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found I needed to make that small change.